# SYSV vs. Linux/GNU ELF formats

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

The question is in the context of the following question: [Why are libraries not found, even though they are clearly on the -L path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782514/why-are-libraries-not-found-even-though-they-are-clearly-on-the-l-path?noredirect=1#comment78524473_45782514) . It seems that my libraries and my object file have a different ELF format, which might cause the linker to not "find" the libraries.

Now, this leads to a couple of questions:

1. It seems that my compiler normally generates SYSV ELF files. (Checked with `file`). However, for that particular C++ source, it generates a Linux/GNU ELF object file. I wonder why, so I reduced that source to an empty main method - and suddenly I get a SYSV object file. **What inside a C++ source file can cause the compiler to switch the ELF format?**
2. **Is it true or false that I can not link Linux/GNU together with SYSV ELF?**
3. **Is there an option to force the compiler to create a certain ELF format?**

I'm working with a Cray g++ (GCC) 5.3.0 20151204.

Comment: Did you find anything out?

Comment: @DustinOprea: Not really. The problem had a completely different cause. But since it finally worked without solving the SYSV issue, I conclude that it's probably possible to link the formats together.

Comment: I was going down this path as well, having a loader 'symbol lookup error' though the symbol is plainly in the right .so and the 'linkee' is showing the right file per ldd

Comment: 6 yrs past no upvoted answer, somebody call some binutils guy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1: one of the answer seems to be that functions of type `STT_GNU_IFUNC` will cause the compiler/linker to switch the `ELF` file format of the corresponding object file from `SYSV` to `GNU/Linux`.

However, I still couldn't find out how I can identify functions in an object file which have type `STT_GNU_IFUNC`. Looking at object files which are `GNU/Linux` with `objdump`, `readelf` and `nm` still don't show a single function of type `STT_GNU_IFUNC`.

Some more information on `STT_GNU_IFUNC` can be found at https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/403 and in the following related question: [How do I compile on linux to share with all distributions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764533/how-do-i-compile-on-linux-to-share-with-all-distributions)