# LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work for current directory (library has correct architecture)

Tags: linker, linker-errors, elf

I have an executable and its dependency libraries in the same path, but the former isn't finding the latter:

```
$ LD_LBRARY_PATH='.' ./img_matcher
./img_matcher: error while loading shared libraries: libmlx_common_atoms.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ file img_matcher
img_matcher: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=7cd572700424d204833657090a7e25b98ec3b819, not stripped

$ file libmlx_common_atoms.so 
libmlx_common_atoms.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=167baeeefe4b2692b455d38571dc85328ce8ed7f, not stripped
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that one is `SYSV`, and the other is `GNU/Linux` may have something to do with it.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45783759/50617

Comment: Hmm. I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.