# How can I force gcc/g++ to create SYSV exectables instead of GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, gnu, sysv

I'm trying to build executables (both programs and *shared objects*) on a relatively modern Linux distro (`A`) and wanting to run those on a fairly old one (`B`).
`A` can build *SYSV* but sometimes it falls back to *GNU/Linux*, causing problems when running such executables on `B` (`B` refuses to run as such).

How can I force *gcc/g++* (or the linker) to build *SYSV* only executables?
If not possible a follow-up question would be what is triggering/forcing *gcc/g++* to adopt *GNU/Linux* convention instead of *SYSV* (expanded on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783759/sysv-vs-linux-gnu-elf-formats) question)?
How can I prevent such linkage from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no **formal** way to do so (even passing the linker flag `-Wl,--hash-style=sysv` may not work depending on the code one has compiled).

The linker will try to default to *SYSV* but then use *GNU/Linux* when necessary.
Conditions that trigger this behaviour are (at least)

1. `STT_GNU_IFUNC` - Basically having functions with such attributes: `__attribute__(ifunc(...))` - This code has to go unfortunately
2. The compiler flag `gnu-unique-object` has to be disabled (i.e. the compiler you're using has to be configured and built with flag `--disable-gnu-unique-object`)

By performing the above, the linker *should* use *SYSV* hash style table when producing executables.

---

Bonus: if you then want to compile your code to be runnable on on older Linux distros, you may want to force include during your compile stages [these headers](https://github.com/wheybags/glibc_version_header). You would also want to build your custom `libstdc++` with such headers and then ship it with your binaries.