# How to link SYSV and GNU/Linux shared libs

Tags: linux, elf, binutils

```
file /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100 
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e534adc24d3ba924851e5a11dc9eee87d5008d36, stripped
file /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9 
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=2a6d6bf1318da7a8593b96359b3c8a66008744ee, stripped
```

Notice that these two differ in the way of (SYSV) vs (GNU/Linux).

gcc/c++ linker cannot link them,`` libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.9: undefined reference to `avio_close@LIBAVFORMAT_FFMPEG_56' `` which is actually defined in this file.

Having problem link against these 2 libs in my project, `libopencv_highgui.so` depends on `libavcodec-ffmpeg.so`. I noticed that on my system they two have different file info (some type), the order of the `-l` flags for them is correct (`libavcodec-ffmpeg.so` comes after), don't know how to get them linked.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45783759/sysv-vs-linux-gnu-elf-formats but it doesn't have an upvoted answer and I'm hesitant to upvote the one it has.

Comment: Same topic, but that is a compound big question in that post.